# Shared tsconfig.json and relative paths

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

My team is maintaining multiple packages and we are trying to create a shared `tsconfig.json` with common configuration for all of them. It contains our preferences about compile target, JSX, output directory and included files, for example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "build/dist"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

We publish this file as a shared npm-module, like `my-build-config` and then use `extends` in every project:

```
{
   "extends": "./node_modules/my-build-config/tsconfig.json"
}
```

The issue here is that all paths in the shared config are relative to the file location. E.g. it will try to include ".ts" files not from the current project, but inside `my-build-config`. For example, instead of `./src/index.ts` it looks for `./node_modules/my-build-config/src/index.ts`.

Is there a way to share file locations, so they will not be repeated in 10+ packages? Maybe something similar what Jest does with [`rootDir`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#rootdir-string) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know `my-build-config` will always be installed at `node_modules/my-build-config` relative to each project without symlinks, you could just prepend `../../` to each affected path.

Alternatively, use a different tool to copy your `tsconfig.json` into all the projects, such as [Braid](http://cristibalan.github.io/braid/) (disclosure: I'm a Braid contributor).

Comment: I gave this a try, works well for now. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: That relative path solution is not good, because node_modules structure sometimes does not match expectations.